# Wordpress thumbnails wont show (Upload error?)

Tags: php, wordpress

Please tell me if this is already a Post for Server fault. I've posted it here, because i don't know what's the problem.

I'm on a WordPress project for a client and i struggle with the image uploads on my server. My files are hosted by a host in my Country.

Whenever i try to upload an image, it looks like this:

[image]

> But when i edit the image, the image shows up.

When i try to access the image uRL for example this one:

http://example.com/woohoo/wp-content/uploads/Screenshot-2015-09-21-10.31.41.png

i get an 403 error.

[image]

And like you see in the second screenshot the uploads folder is empty. I've just installed WordPress and a theme and the theme is also not showing up in the FTP client.

The uploaded Folder has 710 access rights like the themes folder. Do i have to change the access rights or is it not possible by me and i have to contact the host?

Any help much appreciated

Comment: Change the permissions to 755 where you need to upload the data. 710 sounds awfully weird,

Comment: @Runthis Awsome! Thank you! I thought it is because of this!